# Cannot open include file 'rpcerr.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rpc

I was happily compiling and running source code today.  Then I added a few lines to one of my modules, and suddenly Visual Studio 2012 refused to compile the code, with the error message:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rpcerr.h':  No such file or directory.

I'm not sure why the compiler suddenly needs to find `rpcerr.h`.  I'm not doing anything I wasn't doing yesterday, but now I can't make the error go away.

I also have not been able to find `rpcerr.h`, myself.  The reference is in `rpc.h`, which is part of the Visual Studio library.  I'm guessing it got linked in because I included `<windows.h>`.  But I don't know where I can find `rpcerr.h`, or what this file is supposed to do.

I would really like to go forward with this development.  I'm guessing the code tried to compile `rpcerr.h` for a good reason, and that if I'm going to be using `rpc.h` for whatever reason this gets compiled into my source code, then I should get `rpcerr.h` as well.  But trying to find it is sending me into a mobius loop.

Currently, the compiler is only complaining about `rpcerr.h`.

Comment: It should not be used, rpcnterr.h is the correct #include.  You should only get this if MAC or _MAC are #defined.  In other words, when you target an Apple Macintosh.  Pretty hard to guess how that could have happened from here, watch out for stray macaronis in your code.

Comment: Thank you, Hans.  That certainly changes the direction of my search.

Comment: I found the offending header file.  It came from a 3rd party source, and was trying to use the macro MAC as part of the data link layer, and I'd guessed that was was rpc.h was trying to do, too (although I always did consider the possibility that rpc.h could have been trying to support Macintoshes for some reason).

I changed the name of the macro MAC, and everything works, now.

Answer (score 2):

I'd better write this up, this is bound to happen again sooner or later.  The `<rpc.h>` SDK file is stone cold old and dates back to the days that Microsoft supported writing code for an Apple Macintosh.  It still supports it, there's an #include for rpcerr.h.  But that file is no longer supplied, only rpcnterr.h is available.

You need to scan your source, or recently added #includes, for the a #define for `MAC` or `_MAC`, the one that Microsoft uses to select a Macintosh target.  Using the editor's "Go To Definition" context menu command is the easiest way.

Or use this as a workaround:

```
#undef MAC
#undef _MAC
#include <rpc.h>
```

Or change the order of #includes.  Beware that these workarounds might have side-effects, depending on how the other definition is used.

Comment: Based on what I've read on the web google-searching for answers, it seems to happen a lot.

Comment: Problems with macros happen a lot.